# How to avoid multiple design elaborations in Chisel testers

Tags: chisel

In Chisel iotesters, we pass a factory that creates a Chisel design to the tester, e.g. () => new DUT, as follows:

```
"Test" should "simulate" in {
  chisel3.iotesters.Driver.execute(arguments, () => new DUT) { c => new MyPeekPokeTester(c) }  should be (true)
}
```

If I have many tests and a large design, there's design elaboration that happens for every test resulting in a long runtime. Since for many tests, it is possibly exact same design being passed, a logical question comes up - is there a way to reuse the elaborated design (DUT.fir or DUT.v depending on the backend) in multiple tests? Given a reset is called in the beginning of every test, it shouldn't incur functional issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest building a PeekPokeTester that aggregates a number of testers. Something like

```
class MyMegaPeekPokeTester(c: MyDut) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {
  new MyPeekPokeTester1(c) &&
  new MyPeekPokeTester2(c) &&
  ...
  new MyPeekPokeTesterN(c)
}
```

There's various ways you could sugar this up (putting the classes into a list, calling reset between them programmatically, etc).

There's an effort to refactor and modernize the testers and this issue is under consideration. One complication is that PeekPokeTesters require access to the instance of the dut in order to provide type safe access to the IO.  It is difficult to serialize or otherwise preserve this information.

Comment: It is an option I believe. But I'd like still to map each individual test to scala test, so that I get the benefits of scala tests, e.g. one identifying quickly which test failed. I couldn't figure out how to sugar this up to enable this. Another issue can be with waveforms I suspect - I don't want everything in one file.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how this might work better for you. I see the problem with waveforms. I'm wondering if it would help if there were an execute method that passed both the backend and the elaborated Dut to the code block. That would allow you to twiddle the options on the backend (like turning vcd off and on) before each backend. This would all be a lot easier if we could persist/serialize the dut description so it could be then used in different tests, we've looked into this a fair amount lately but we haven't found a good solution yet

Comment: I'd like having scalatest should "simulate" in around inner peekpoketesters as opposed to outer. I don't mind the waveforms much, but would like to know which test fail and not stop at the first failing test which it does.

I am using what you suggest now with my original separate tests. I use to run all of them at once for sanity before committing, but when debugging I use individual test harness. I think that's fine for now